# What attributes are accessible for 'error' objects in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, error-handling

I am working on adding error handling into my Google Sheets based web app. After investigating try/catch blocks, it's clear that it would be best practice to specify what action to take depending on the exact nature of the error. I have begun testing with errors, but I am unable to find a complete resource that details exactly what attributes of the error can be utilized. For reference, here is the try/catch block in my test function:

```
try{
    var url = "jdbc:mysql://"+SERVER+":"+PORT+"/"+DB_DEV;
    var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    // Sends connection to prepare SQL statements
    return conn;
  } catch(e){
    Logger.log(e);          
    Logger.log(e.stack);    // Valid
    Logger.log(e.message);  // Valid
    Logger.log(e.name);     // Valid

    Logger.log(e.type);     // Invalid

    return null;
  }
```

In the above example, "stack", "message", and "name" are all valid attributes, but I was only able to find them via trial and error looking through others' example code. My question is - could someone point me in the direction of a resource that would detail error objects in Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps script uses a standard chrome v8 engine based on javascript. All standard properties of the [javascript error object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#instance_properties) are available(i.e., `name` and `message`).  Some non standard properties like [`stack` is also available on the v8 engine](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration?hl=en#avoid_using_errorfilename_and_errorlinenumber).